# Should I flag a question where OP misunderstood the problem for deletion?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Yesterday, I came [into a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108994/keycloak-admin-rest-api-returns-only-5-users-out-of-58) where the OP thought there was some problem with a server API and/or client library. I made some comments in order to point him in the right direction to be able to test/debug the issue. In the end, it was a matter of the library pointing out the wrong server.

As the issue here comes from a misconfiguration of the library, I don't think it even deserves for it to have the OP write an answer with this kind of content:

> Oops, sorry this was my fault. I had the client library configured to point B server instead of A.

This would have little value for the community, considering the first thing to do when using the tool is to set up the basic configuration. Also the question title keeps referencing an issue which is not the real problem, which could mislead future searchers. So I thought it was better for the question to be deleted and told him to do it in the comments.

The question is, if he doesn't delete it, what should I do considering my privileges are still below "Trusted user"? Should I keep asking him to remove it? Mayble flag the question for a moderator or cast a closure vote?

Comment: I'd just vote to close it as a problem that can no longer be reproduced. There's no real reason to bother moderators about it as long as it's not causing any harm and most likely it will fade away and get auto-deleted eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vote to close the question with this close reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Once the question is closed, it will be unlikely to mislead anyone.  It might fulfil the criteria for automatic deletion at some point, and thus disappear without any action required.